# Service or technology developer portal is using to render the RALM

Tags: spotify

The https://beta.developer.spotify.com/ and https://beta.developer.spotify.com/
uses which service or technology to generate the UI? I know spotify uses RAML but use which tool/service to generate the UI, the descriptions and endpoint call e etc?

Answer (score 1):

We hand-wrote the code that interprets our RAML and generates our API console. It uses a build script to generate Jekyll files with each of the endpoint's data, and a React component that grabs that data when the page gets loaded, presents a UI, and handles network requests. Source: I'm one of the devs who wrote that code! If you're looking to build something similar without having to write the code yourself, you could check out this [api-console](https://github.com/mulesoft/api-console) by Mulesoft. Hope that helps!